AppImage .desktop file not showing on launcher
On Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I put a .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/ for an AppImage (LibreCAD), but I can' get it to show on launcher, even after rebooting. The .appimage is placed at /home/ksio89/Applications and has read/write/execute permissions, as I can run it. Here's the content of librecad.desktop, I just can't see what's wrong and why it's not shown on launcher:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=LibreCAD
GenericName=CAD system
Comment=A professional CAD System
Comment[pt_BR]=Um sistema CAD profissional
TryExec=librecad
Exec=/home/ksio89/Applications/LibreCAD.AppImage %F
Icon=/home/ksio89/Applications/icons/librecad.svg
Categories=Graphics;Engineering;
MimeType=image/vnd.dxf;
X-AppImage-Version=2.2.1_rc3-25-g29c9abab

I then removed the .desktop and tried AppImageLauncher so it sets up everything for me, but when I choose "Run and Integrate", I get this error message:



That's version 2.2.0.2, I want to install build 2.2.1 and newer builds, which are only available as an AppImage package.

You might find this video from Jay at Learn Linux TV of some help on installing and using AppiImages. Particularly look at 8 minutes in where it tellys you that not all AppImages offer to create Launchers.

The .desktop-file looks ok, I wonder why it didn't work. Probably you need to make the .desktop-file executable.

@mook765 I have now covered that in my answer. Thanks.

as regards your edit "failed to register Appimage..." this AU Q&A may be helpful

Yeah, guess this AppImage just does not support a desktop file. Really wish the project maintaners provided .deb packages, which just work;

First thing to consider once downloaded in order to run an AppImage will be to right click on the app in the download directory, navigate to Properties -> Permissions and then check the Execute box.
Whilst not all AppImages offer to create launchers, there is a Github AppImageLauncher which integrates AppImages to your application launcher with one click to manage, update and remove them from there. Double-click AppImages to open them without having to make them executable first as outlined above.

You can select either Run once or Integrate and run according to your preference.
To install on Ubuntu or Debian based systems there are two main ways.
Use the PPA's
To add the PPA to your system, you can execute the following commands:
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appimagelauncher-team/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install appimagelauncher

Install directly from Github
Note: The main drawback from using GitHub is that you won't receive updates automatically. Please make sure to check the release page from time to time to download the latest and greatest versions.
First, download the package suitable for your system. There's support for all still-supported Ubuntu releases, Debian oldstable and newer as well as all derivatives (e.g., Linux Mint) for 32-bit and 64-bit Intel/AMD CPU based systems (state: Feb 2020). For newer releases,  ARM devices are also supported (32-bit and 64-bit) such as the Raspberry Pi and the Pinebook.
Go to the latest release page and download the suitable .deb file. If in doubt, please consult the compatibility table in the README or open an issue so we can update the table
After downloading, open the .deb file. In most distributions, the software center should allow you to install it graphically
If that is not possible, you can install the tool from the terminal using the following command:
cd ~/Downloads/
sudo dpkg -i appimagelauncher-*.deb

If you encounter error messages regarding missing dependencies, the following commands usually fix the problem:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f

References
LearnLinuxTV video
Github AppImageLauncher
Release Build page
All acknowledgements to LearnLinuxTV and The Assassin
